# Number of combinations of football pool

Tags: algorithm, function, vba, excel

I have developed a macro in VBA which combines three triples of football pools representing the 27 different combinations. 27 represents the max possible combinations of betting.  I would like to modify the list in a way to develop a system with double, fixed, triple prediction;

For  example, now the program only works for:

```
1st  game   1 x 2 
2nd game   1 x 2 
3rd game   1 x 2
```

equal to `(3 * 3 * 3 = 27  possible combinations)`

but if the prediction was the following:

```
1st game   1 x
2nd game   1
3rd game   1 x 2
```

equal to `(2 * 1 * 3 = 6 possible combinations)`

Now : first game 1 x 2 , second 1 x 2 ,third 1 x 2 ,equal to (3 * 3 * 3 = 27 combinations) but if the prediction should be the following: first game 1 x, second 1 , third  x 2 , equal to (2 * 1 * 3 = 6 combinations) should be printed only valid columns.

Thank you in advance who can help me to solve the problem.

```
 Sub Combination_Prediction()

   Dim A As Integer
   Dim B As Integer
   Dim C As Integer
   Dim Col1Sviluppo As Integer
   Dim Row1Sviluppo As Integer

 Col1Sviluppo = 10
 Row1Sviluppo = 14

 For C = 3 To 5
     For B = 3 To 5
          For A = 3 To 5
               Contatore = Contatore + 1
               Col1Sviluppo = Col1Sviluppo + 1
               Cells(Row1Sviluppo + 1, Col1Sviluppo) = Cells(2, A)
               Cells(Row1Sviluppo + 2, Col1Sviluppo) = Cells(3, B)
               Cells(Row1Sviluppo + 3, Col1Sviluppo) = Cells(4, C)
               Cells(10, 10) = Contatore & " colonne elaborate"
         Next A
     Next B
    Next C
  End Sub
```

Comment: Now : first  game 1 x 2 , second 1 x 2 ,third  1 x 2 ,equal to (3 * 3 * 3 = 27 combinations)

but if the prediction should be the following: first game  1 x, second 1 , third  1 x 2 , equal to (1 * 2 * 3 = 6 combinations) should be printed only valid columns.

Comment: I stared at this question for ages (and went to read about football pools and how they work) in the hope of helping you, but I'm afraid I really can't understand what you are asking. Could you edit your post to clarify with exactly what output you are getting, and what you want? Please use the code block formatting for anything where the layout of the text is meaningful and explain any non-standard notation you are using (I can't work out the two examples you give above your code block and in your first comment above).

Comment: It 's the normal mechanism of the stakes in the game of football pools (bet.) If there are three games, the possible outcomes are 1X2 for each match(win, draw, defeat), so if you'd want to guess, the combinations are 27 (3x3x3,the VBA code to create these 27 combinations is shown above). If I change my bet so:  1X fixed for a game, 1 for the second game and 1X2 for the third, the combinations down to 6(2x1x3). I am looking for a routine to represent e write this with VBA. thanks

Comment: OK, I still don't understand how you are using the following notations: `* ^ x X` - sometimes you seem to use `*` for multiply, sometimes you use `x`, and you're distinguishing between `x` and `X` in some way I don't understand (but I think sometimes you use `X` and sometimes you use `^` to mean the same thing?) If the answer below helps you that is fine. If not then come back and comment / edit further.

Comment: OK, I've just found the bit about "Continental European pools" on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football_pools so presumably you are using that notation with an X. For future reference, if you want to get help with this kind of thing it's much better to give all the necessary background rather than assuming we know it or can work it out for ourselves.

Comment: Vicky :) calm down a bit :) its a bit strange notation but if u knew about betting you would distinguish the difference with no trouble.

Comment: @mehow, don't worry, I'm not un-calm about it! Just trying to help Pierre write questions in the future that stand a better chance of getting answered. The number of people on SO who could answer his question AND who understand the particular notation of European football pools is very small, but the number who could have answered the question if he'd just given a bit more background or explained his notation is much higher. It's a perfectly generic combinatorics problem that just happens to be dressed up in a particular set of terminology.

Comment: *The number of people on SO who could answer his question AND who understand the particular notation of European football pools is very small* - this is a really bad assumption!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: *your logic is based on unpredictable assumptions. Please do not relay on it if youre betting real money. It's all more complicated then you think it is. There is only one reliable way of betting and earning (requires a lot of money to get started and proper and good understanding of bookmakers policies) and it's called **sure bet**s.* But please, do not get into it.

Now, back to your original question.

You can have a function return the number of combinations based on the input » **combinations multipliers**

Let's assume that

```
combinations multipliers
1 - 1
2 - 1X
3 - 1X2
```

`1` represents either home or away win, `1` combination

`2` stands for home win or draw, away win or draw, `2` combinations

`3` is default: win, draw, win

The code:

```
Sub Combination_Prediction()

    ' combinations multipliers
    ' 1 - 1
    ' 2 - 1X
    ' 3 - 1X2

    Range("A1") = Combination(3, 3, 3) ' 1x2, 1x2, 1x2
    Range("B2") = Combination(2, 1, 3) ' 1x, 1, 1x2

End Sub

Function Combination(c1 As Long, c2 As Long, c3 As Long) As Long

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, combinationMultiplier As Long
    combinationMultiplier = 0

    For i = 1 To c1
        For j = 1 To c2
            For k = 1 To c3
                combinationMultiplier = combinationMultiplier + 1
            Next k
        Next j
    Next i

    Combination = combinationMultiplier
End Function
```

If you ran this code, you will see in Cell `A1` number `27` which is the *correct* (*and simplified*) calculation of possible bets.

The `Combination()` function takes 3 parameters which are the `3` combinations.

In the first example the first input is `3, 3, 3` as *from your sample*

> 1st game = 1x2
>
> 2nd game = 1x2
>
> 3rd game = 1x2

Now look at the ***combinations multipliers*** above

> 1st game = 1x2 = 3
>
> 2nd game = 1x2 = 3
>
> 3rd game = 1x2 = 3

Therefore, your 3 parameters are: `3, 3, 3`

The second sample *you provided*

> 1st game = 1x = 2
>
> 2nd game = 1 = 1
>
> 3rd game = 1x2 = 3

therefore `Combination(2, 1, 3)` will return `6` (*combinations*) to Cell `A2`

Stick any combination of `1, 2, 3` into the combination function to get results. You can either print them to cell or use `msgbox` or `debug.print` for testing.

I hope that helps